# I am only 70% complete, but have finished all the side missions, what am I missing?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have finished all secondary campaigns in *Batman: Arkham City* (including Riddler trophies/challenges) and have almost everything (level 41), but am only 70% complete.  What major things could I be missing?

Comment: I tried to fix the question, but it still seems extremely narrow as in a game like this everyone will have random bits left undone unless they're being extremely methodical.

Comment: 30% left of completing... There must be something big

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To reach 100% completion you also have to complete New Game Plus, which is harder.
The side missions are re-activated so you can redo them if you want. However, this is *not necessary* as missions in the first playthrough already count towards 100%.

Comment: Ahhh there we go then :P

Comment: but it's a bit boring to do all the main campaign again =/

Comment: Well...don't do it then? :) I haven't tried it yet, I intend to wait until I *really* want to play the game again so that it's all exciting again. There are a few major differences, primarily the lack of counter indicators and tougher/more varied thugs, seen here: http://www.ign.com/wikis/batman-arkham-city/New_Game_Plus

Comment: Honestly, New Game+ seems more fun to me than the regular mode. Not getting the notifications on when to counter just seems to make the game more exciting.

Comment: I don't know if you have to do the sidemissions in New Game+ to get 100%. But they don't carry over. Only riddler trophies and riddles are shared.

Comment: @user13278 I don't think you have to. They don't carry over so you get the chance to do them again, but they still count as completed (I *think*)

Answer (score 1):

To get 100% completion of the game you first have to beat the game on normal or hard then complete the side missions that follow.The only missable side mission is watcher in the wings;here is azreals apearences
After the court section of the game across the court house
After the steel mill on top of the Ferris wheel
After interrogating major sharp on a building
After rescuing Vicki vale on a building
Then you must get every riddle trophy and collectible to unlock all campaigns and maps look up on line where to find them all.
Then get the exploration trophies,visit calendar man on different holidays,find crime alley and pay your respects to Bruce's parents,then glide off wonder tower and keep goings towards the city and turn around when your pulled back for about a minute for that trophy
Then do the riddler challenges and campaigns.Note that you must earn 2 trophies also such as not taking damage and putting all of batman a moves into a combo
Then beat new game +

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete all riddler challenges which is on the main menu when you want to start the game. You have to complete all challengers as all four characters and earn the highest medal on each challenge